# smtp.office365.com:25: Exception reading response: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?

Tags: maven, pom.xml

```
<mailhost>smtp.gmail.com</mailhost>
<!-- port of the host -->
<mailport>465</mailport>
<mailssl>true</mailssl>
<mailAltConfig>true</mailAltConfig>
```

what i have to write here in tag for starttls?
It is a pom file configuration with post man plug in.

Comment: Please specify technologies you're using it tags

Comment: I am using Maven with Post Man plugin and Suirefire plugin to send auto mail with attachment.
Outgoing Mail (SMTP) Server: smtp.office365.com
Port: 587
Type of Encrypted Connection: TSL